# Puedo detectar de alguna manera cuando algun elemento esta en :hover con javascript?

Tags: html

lo que queria saber es si hay alguna manera de saber cuanto algun elemento esta en **hover**, me serviría mucho para remover clases o agregar clases en JS, ya que algunas cosas se desactivan cuando no esta en hover mi div.

Logre hacer algo pero se desactiva con el tiempo y para ativarlo de nuevo le tienes que vovler a clickear:

´´´

```
function prueba(carta = card) {
document.querySelectorAll(".cajaGrafico").forEach(item => {
    item.classList.remove('pointerEvents');
});

setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".cajaGrafico").forEach(item => {
        item.classList.add('pointerEvents');
    });
console.log('se acabo el tiempo');
}, 20000 );
```

}

```
.card:hover {
    z-index: 8;
    transform: scale(1.12);
    box-shadow: 9px 40px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: #292929;
}  
´´´
```

Comment: Probablemente puedas usar el evento de ratón "onmouseover" y "onmouseout"

Comment: Lo que buscas es que cuando el div se le haga hover se le ponga la clase y que no se le vuelva a eliminar luego de quitar el hover?

Comment: lo que busco es que me haga como una "Bandera" si esta lo esta en hover me haga 1 y si le quito el hover me haga 0, para poder hacer un if que agregue o me quite clases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar los eventos mouseenter - mouseover y mouseleave - mouseout, con eso le agregas la clase dependiendo el evento que quieras, mira el ejemplo:

```js
let test = document.getElementById("test");

test.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
  event.target.style.background = "purple";
});


test.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {
  event.target.style.background = "orange";
});
```

```css
#test{
width:20px;
height: 20px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id=test>

</div>
```

o tambien así:

```js
    let open = true;

    function change() {
            document.getElementById("test").className = "closed";
            open = true; 
    }
    function change2() {
    document.getElementById("test").className = "open";
            open = false;
    }
```

```css
p.closed {
    display: none;
}
p.open {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="change()" onmouseout=change2()>Mostar/no mostrar</div>

<p id="test" class="open">Esto se mostrara dependiendo la clase</p>
```

Comment: Gracias por las respuesta! me sirvio.