# Animación al sacar el cursor

Tags: css, hover, transicion

tengo entendido que hay el :hover añadiendo una animacion al pasar el ratón por encima del elemento deseado ( junto con animation y transition..etc). Queria saber si al sacar el raton del elemento podria hacerse una animacion reversal. Por ejemplo tengo un botón y hago que al pasar el ratón se haga mas grande en 0.5s, entonces y al sacar el raton queda una "transicion" muy cortada para q vuelva a su estado original y lo que yo quisiera es que al sacar el ratón se pueda hacer esa transicion de 0.5s pero en reversa y no quede tan seco al sacar el ratón

Comment: Recuerda poner el código de lo que has echo, así te podemos ayudar mejor.

Comment: exactamente aqui no se necesitaba codigo, es una situación en general, no hay un codigo en especifico

Comment: entonces usa mouseenter - mouseover y mouseleave - mouseout. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/535333/puedo-detectar-de-alguna-manera-cuando-algun-elemento-esta-en-hover-con-javascr/535344#535344  asi le agregas las clases y puedes hacer las animaciones que necesitas

Comment: Perfecto! gracias

Comment: Aunque sea una "situación en general", es recomendable que agregues algo de código a tu pregunta para seguir las normas de la comunidad. En caso contrario, tu preguntase cierra y deja de recibir respuestas. [Pásate por acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que comprendas de lo que hablo.

Comment: vale, a la proxima lo pongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira lo puedes hacer así con esto cambias el tamaño como quieras

```js
function change() {
            document.querySelector(".cuadro").classList.remove("aumentar");
    }
    
        function change2() {
    document.querySelector(".cuadro").classList.add("aumentar");
    }
```

```css
.cuadro{
  background: red;
  height:100px;
  transition: width .5s;
  width:100px;
}

.aumentar{
  width:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cuadro" onmouseover="change2()" onmouseout=change()></div>
```

Comment: Gracias! creeo que eso se puede aplicar a cualquier elemento que quiera tener ese efecto? y no pensaba q necesitaria JS xd venia en busca de solo html y css, pero veo que con cosas asi la programación es inevitable

Answer (score 1):

Si es posible lograrlo sin `JS` usando las propiedades `transition` de `CSS`.

Este es un ejemplo de un efecto `overlay` tomado de https://codepen.io/ArnaudBalland/pen/vGZKLr

En el ejemplo, para `transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;` tenemos:

- **transition-property (all):** Indica que se aplicarán todas las propiedades declaradas
- **transition-duration (0.4s):** Indica que la transición durará 0.4 segundos
- **transition-timing-function (ease-in-out):** Indica que la transición será lenta al inicio y al final
- **transition-delay (0s):** Indica que el número de segundos antes de iniciar la transición es cero

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  padding: 1em 0;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .container {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }
}

.container {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content .content-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  height: 99%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.content:hover .content-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.content-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.content-details {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.content:hover .content-details {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content-details h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content-details p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.fadeIn-bottom {
  top: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/HkTMcmlMOUQ" target="_blank">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
      <img class="content-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433360405326-e50f909805b3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=359e8e12304ffa04a38627a157fc3362">
      <div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">
        <h3 class="content-title">This is a title</h3>
        <p class="content-text">This is a short description</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

En este otro ejemplo, tenemos una trancisión que cambia el color de fondo y agrega la propiedad `border-radius` al `div`.

Nótese que al "sacar el mouse", el `div` retoma su forma original en la misma fracción de tiempo que se transformó al principio. *Siendo este el ejemplo más claro para tu pregunta*

```css
#propiedades {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  transition-property: background-color, border-radius;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}
#propiedades:hover {
  background-color: #0000ff;
  border-radius: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="propiedades"></div>
```

Comment: oh wow, perfecto muchas gracias

Comment: Si la respuesta cumple tus expectativas, te sugiero aceptarla y darle un voto positivo. De esta manera ambos ganamos reputación en la comunidad y servirá de referencia para futuros visitantes que tengan una duda igual o similar.